# Testing simultaneous calls to transactional service

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, junit, transactional

How should I test a service method that is transactional for its simultaneous use (it updates a database row by decreasing a value)?

I have setup a JUnit test class with SpringJunit4ClassRunner and components are @autowired.

Just spawning threads which would call the method doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure whether this has something to do with the Spring proxy mechanism.

What I would like to achieve is to create a situation where simultaneously two threads are "inside" the tested method and other one will fail and rollback. e.g. The row value is 3 and both method calls try to decrease the value by 2; if the method wouldn't work, the value would be -1, which is illegal. But I want that either both of the calls fail and rollback, or failing the one that tries to update it an instant later than the other.

Is this even possible?

Comment: You should explain exactly what isn't working when spawning threads.

Comment: I either got a nullpointer exception at the very start of the callable method (it was just a private method call) or hibernate exception that said that table didn't exist, which was weird since the same call in a test method that hadn't threads worked fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first problem is that the transaction context is **bound to one thread** (with a thread local). So you have to start a transaction in each of your threads. (I think there is no support for this in spring. You can start transaction programmatically with the [transaction manager](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/PlatformTransactionManager.html).)

The code you described: read, decrement, write does only work with the right **isolation level** (serialized and repeatable read  would work).

After this setup is done, you can test the behavior by blocking one thread while he has the database lock. You can use a [Latch](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) for this.

The thread without database lock will now still not rollback. It will block until the database lock is available again. The scheme you're describing is quite similiar to [Optimistic concurrency control](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-optimistic) so maybe this is already implemented.

Comment: This sounds pretty much what I wanted. I'll try to see if I get everything to work. Thank you!